# Local harddrive links broken

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink

I am experiencing a problem with hardrive link and wordpress.
On an intranet web app, there are hyperlinks which target files are located on the hardrive.
example :

```
<a href="file:///c:/file.xls">target hardrive link, click to open </a>
```

I tried to add the file protocol wp-includes/formatting.php but this has no effect :

```
$protocols = array ('http', 'https', 'ftp', 'ftps', 'mailto', 'news', 'irc', 'gopher', 'nntp', 'feed', 'telnet', 'mms', 'rtsp', 'svn','file');
```

When I click a link, nothing happens;
Does anybody can help me ?
greetings,
ben

Comment: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/create-links-to-files-from-local-intranet#post-3028820

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Mozilla?
If so try this...

```
 file://///servername/share/file.ext
```

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_%3a_Issues_%3a_Links_to_Local_Pages_Don%27t_Work

if that doesn't work this is another example I found.

https://superuser.com/questions/103026/open-a-direct-file-on-the-hard-drive-from-firefox-file

Comment: the problem is  both encuntered with firefox and ie. In my opinion it is a Wordpress issue.